# Tuleap: How to handle versioned wiki documentation

Tags: wiki, tuleap

My situation is like this:

I am evaluating Tuleap v8.2 and I would like to have a project's software documentation (for example architecture and design) in a wiki (as far as I see it is using the PhpWiki engine). I would also like to have trackers for architecture and design (one for each and linked in a hierarchy) where I would basically just add a link to a specific wiki page that corresponds to this artifact.

I already set up the trackers, but I am having issues with how to organize the wiki pages (I have almost no experiences with wikis). The biggest problem is with "versioning" of the documents. As far as I see I have 2 options:

1) make all references to wiki pages with specific (wiki) version

2) organize wiki pages in a way that they are organized in a "version hierarchy", where I would have a "root wiki page" for each software release/version.

The problems see with option 1) is that for a release you would have to go through all artifacts in architecture and design trackers and update the references to wiki pages to link to the specific (latest) version. This could be a lot of work...

The problem I see with option 2) is that I don't see a possibility to copy a "version branch" of wiki pages to a new "version branch".

I guess the option 1) would be the better solution...

And there are also other problems with linking to wiki pages from a tracker:

- It appears that the "reference system" does not play nice with wiki sub-pages. From what I have seen wiki sub-pages can only be made by using a "/" separator in the wiki page's name and this is in conflict with the way parameters are separated in the "reference system".
- It also appears that you are not able to link to wiki pages that have spaces (and I guess other special characters) in the name.

I guess the only solution (at the moment) is to just use the full URL to a wiki page...

**Edit:**

So my question is ... what is the best way to use and organize Tuleap's wiki in my case?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @David: I updated the post with an explicit question :)